# KDE: How to open a link via web shortcut

Tags: kde, plasma

When ever I encounter a URL in a document, that is not a hyperlink, I would like to mark, right click and open it directly.

In KDE the web shortcuts are a way to search for marked text with a preferred search engine. For example, searching for `StackExchange` via MetaGer can be done with this web link:

```
https://metager.de/en/meta/meta.ger3?eingabe=\{@}
```

that is resolved to:

```
https://metager.de/en/meta/meta.ger3?eingabe=http%3A%2F%2Faskubuntu.com
```

and opened in the default browser.

So my first thought was to create a link using only the variable `\{@}` to open a link directly, but that does not work and tries to open this link:

```
file:///home/username/http%3A%2F%2Faskubuntu.com
```

Is there a way to create a web shortcut that opens valid links directly?

Comment: Is this of help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919946/how-to-add-a-option-in-right-click-menu-on-ubuntu#21975376